# I'm trying to use the strptime function and it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python-3.x

I am following a tutorial and trying to use the strptime function to pull out the day of birth after an input of someone's birthday. The code is supposed to tell you what the day before your DOB is. Very simple. I have copied the code exactly as far as I can tell, but it is giving me errors.

I am just trying to make my way through some basic tutorials and I am not familiar enough to figure out what the errors are telling me.

Here is a picture of my code.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQmx4.jpg)

And here is a picture of the errors I am getting. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKMt4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using %y with a lowercase "y". That represents a short two-digit year. %Y with an uppercase "Y" represents the four digit year you are expecting the user to input.